# How to prevent variables showing in URL?

Tags: php, url

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['chgPwd']))
    {
        $oldpwd=$_POST["txtOldPassword"];
        $newpwd=$_POST["txtNewPassword"];
        $cnewpwd=$_POST["txtConfirmNewPassword"];
        //did stuff to get in the text fields
    $oldpass = oci_result($new1,"OLDPASS");
    if($oldpwd!=$oldpass)
        {
            $msg = "The old password does not match with the one in the records";
            header("Location:ErrorPage.php?abc=".$msg);
        }
    } 
    ?>
```

My question here is that when i redirecting my page to the ErrorPage.php, I am able to see the entire page in the URL, which i do not want it to. Is there anyway around this. I am thinking of binding sessions, but i am unable to get it right. Could you please show me the right way if there is any?

Comment: "entire page"? did you mean "entire text"?

Comment: http://www.project.com/shafiq/ErrorPage.php?abc=The%20old%20password%20does%20not%20match%20with%20the%20one%20in%20the%20records
yeah i meant the entire text in the URL as mention in the above URL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should `urlencode($msg) ( string $str )` and perhaps add an `exit()` after header.

Edit: Well, you only want to see `ErrorPage.php` in your browsers URL, right? Without any message or attributes? Then you have to work with SESSIONS (or Cookies) to store the message/location for the current user and then to redirect him back to `ErrorPage` with the individual message.

Comment: i tried that, and it gives me this in the URL;
../shafiq/ErrorPage.php?abc=The+old+password+does+not+match+with+the+one+in+the+records;

it is supposed to be like this isnt it ?the code i mean 
$msg = "The old password does not match with the one in the records";    
header("Location:ErrorPage.php?abc=".urlencode($msg));

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the error page and show your errors oncite.

Here is the sketch of the registration code

```
<?  
include 'config.php';
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {  

  $err = array();
  //performing all validations and raising corresponding errors
  if (empty($_POST['name']) $err[] = "Username field is required";  
  if (empty($_POST['text']) $err[] = "Comments field is required";  

  if (!$err) {  
    // if no errors - saving data 
    // and then redirect:
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    exit;
  }  else {
    // all field values should be escaped according to HTML standard
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
      $form[$key] = htmlspecialchars($val);
    }
} else {
  $form['name'] = $form['comments'] = '';  
}
include 'form.tpl.php';
?>
```

and a *template* contains the form and the error mesages

```
<? if ($err): ?>
  <? foreach($err as $e): ?>
<div class="err"><?=$e?></div>
  <? endforeach ?>
<? endif ?>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="name" value="<?=$form['name']?>">
  <textarea name="comments"><?=$form['comments']?></textarea>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

This is the most common way of form processing called [POST/Redirect/GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

Answer (score 0):

```
header("Location:ErrorPage.php?abc=1");
```

> ErrorPage.php

```
if(isset($_GET['abc'])=="1")
{
 Show Some Message
}
```

Comment: the problem with this is that, i need to use the same page ErrorMessage.php to print the "different" messages that i encounter while doing validations, sending the messages along as a parameter. As a result it shows on the entire msg in the URL. And there are too many cases for errors to show up, so writing cases for all of them is strenous, better thn tht was sending in the msg.....atleast thts wht i thot.....any other way to approach this, now tht i have posted this new constraint???

Comment: so what's the problem redirect to same page and give numbers to error i mean for header("location:".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?error=1"); for error 1 header("location:".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?error=2"); for error 2 just like that and check if(isset($_GET['error'])) { if($_GET['error']=="1") { show error 1 } elseif($_GET['error']=="2") { show error 2 } }

Answer (score -1):

You can use sessions to hide that parameters. It's the simplest way.